# Java Waffle - absolute beginner

Tags: java, kerberos, waffle

We have a site with Kerberos authentication. I've never used Java and Eclipse before, thus my knowledge is very limited.

What I wish to achieve is something like I did with python:

```
def DownloadFileFromSite(url):
    FileName = ''
    if 'download' not in url:
        print ('ERROR: Change the following url to the proper download link.\n' + url)
    else:   
        try:
            # Disable SSL warnings
            requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
            kerberos_auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL)
            response = requests.get(url, auth=kerberos_auth)
            response.raise_for_status()  # Check for exceptions
        except:
            print ('ERROR: HTTP Connection error. Check the network connection, and the inside links in CQ.')
        # If the response has Content-Disposition, we take file name from it
        if 'content-disposition' in response.headers:
            FileName = re.findall("filename=(.+)", response.headers['content-disposition'])
            if FileName:
                FileName = FileName[0]
        # if we were redirected, we take the real file name from the final URL
        else:
            FileName = re.search(r'/([^/;]+)(;.*)?$', response.url)
            if FileName:
                FileName = FileName.group(1)
        # Save the downloaded file to C:\temp
        if FileName:
            try:
                with open(strWorkspace + '\\' + FileName, 'wb') as DownloadedFile:
                    DownloadedFile.write(response.content)
            except:
                print ('\nError occured while saving downloaded contents from site.\n')
        else:
            print ('ERROR:  ' + url)
```

I would like to achieve this in Java, however I have no idea how to start. I've seen examples, but I'm such a newbie in Java that I have no idea what to do with them.

Comment: At least try something :)

Comment: I've been trying all day and I failed miserably. I know I'm terrible at Java, I don't want to use Java, but for this task, and only for this task I have to.